# How can we verify whether gzip/deflate compression has worked in IE browsers or not?

Tags: internet-explorer, content-encoding

In our Apache web server, we have enabled deflate compression.  This has improved the speed of our site. We could verify this deflate compression in browsers other than IE by the looking at the value "Content-Encoding: gzip".  We used tools like firebug to identify this content-encoding value.

We are happy to see how the content size has reduced.

The issue is: We want to verify the same in IE using IE web developer tool (F12).  But we couldn't verify as the content-coding key is not appearing there at all.

How can we verify whether gzip/deflate compression has worked in IE browsers or not?

UPDATE:

I learnt from the following link that IE developer tool does not display even if it processes gzipped content.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/07/23/i-don-t-see-content-encoding-header-in-ie-http-debugger-f12-developer-tools.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that F12 before IE11 doesn't show the compressed size but with IE11 and the most recent updates you should see the compressed size. Let me know if not.

Comment: In the network tab?  We should see the compressed size in the "received" column, rather than the uncompressed size?  I'm not seeing this compared to Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

With IE11 I can open Tools > F12 Developer Tools, refresh the page, click to enable network traffic monitoring (F5) and see on the Network tab, after double-clicking on the document page, the Request-Headers, accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, and under Response Headers, Content-Length, which confirms it is compressed.